# How to install Windows8 App on a test Tablet (i.e. not the developer machine); error about signature being corrupt

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-8.1

I've been working on a C# application that will end up on the App store to run on Windows 8.1 Tablets.

Target Platform Version : Windows 8.1
Output type: "Windows Store App"

I can run the app in the IDE, "Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows", and I can "Create App Package"

I'm selecting "NO" when asked if I want to upload to the Store, and it produces a

```
X.Win8_1.0.0.0_Debug_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1
X.Win8_1.0.0.0_Debug_Test\...etc
X.Win8_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_bundle_Debug.appxupload
```

I can run the .ps1 file on my dev machine, and it installs the cert and application fine.

If I copy these files to the test-tablet (Hewlett-Packard  Business-Notebook Intel Atom), then it wont install it since..

```
"the package or bundle is not digitally signed or its signature is corrupted"
```

The steps I've followed are.. [How to deploy app](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx)

So my question is...

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get the message about the signature, is what I'm trying impossible?

Note: The Architecture selected is "Neutral"

---

I've looked in the registry of the tablet devices for the following.

Use RegEdit to navigate to the key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx
Set AllowAllTrustedApps (REG_DWORD) to the value of 1

I don't have the entry for "Appx" in my registry.
Just...
CurrentVersion
EnhancedStorageDevices
IPSec
Network Connections
NetworkConnectivityStatsIndicator
safer
System
WcmSvc
WSDAPI

---

AHH!

It looks like the tablet is Windows8 and the app is Windows 8.1!

Could this be my woe!?!?!?

Comment: Did you change the registry value on the non-dev machine?

Comment: What registry value? (off I scurry to google this)

Comment: see above comments in the question.

Comment: See this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx

Comment: I'd say probably.  You can retarget to 8.0 and see if it works.

Answer (score 6):

YES!

Updating the other machine to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8.0 works!

So if you get the message...

```
"the package or bundle is not digitally signed or its signature is corrupted"
```

Then it *can* mean the app you have is targeted for Windows 8.0 and you are on Windows 8.1

Comment: Not always. I've seen this message for different users on the same machine

Comment: I believe it can also be a permissions thing. I seem to see errors like this if my user doesn't have admin permissions